# Add UIButtons to a ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I'd like to display 5 Buttons in a ScrollView Box but unfortunately the code I wrote has no effects on my UIButtons (I can't Scroll up or Down , can you tell me why ?

Thanks for you help, I spent a lot of hours on it (Rookie) but i still can't find the solution...

My Code :

**FirstViewController.h :**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;
UIButton *button;
UIButton *button2;
UIButton *button3;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll;

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m :**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize button;
@synthesize button2;
@synthesize button3;
@synthesize scroll;


- (IBAction)goToViewTwo {
        }

- (void)viewDidload {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake (500, 1000)];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [button release];
    [scroll release];
}                                      
@end
```

**Hierarchy in FirstView.xib:**

```
View
  Action Sheet
  Text View
  ScrollView
    Button
    Button
    Button
```

About the Outlets :

- Scrollview is linked to File's Owner with "Scroll"
- View is linked to File's Owner as  a "view"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're implementing the scroll in Interface Builder and that the app is for iPad (for the contentSize). See if you have the same configuration in IB and in code, especially that `[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];`

Comment: Thx for your answer, i checked IB and i don't see my error :x , can you give me your opinion about it :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/146/capturedcran20110510130.png/

Comment: OK, the XIB is fine. Have you added the buttons as scroll's subviews or as it's parent's (self.view) subviews?